# What is the best way to design file handling using spring

Tags: spring

I want to make an application is which file handling is used. That is file downloading (get the file), file parsing(process the file) and file uploading. It is not a web project. Actually the idea is we make this project and then make a jar of it and then use it in our further projects. How can i design my application so it is extendable easily in future. Is there is any spring framework for this task?

Thanks

Comment: Spring Batch has lots of features regarding file processing. It may be helpful to your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest either [Spring Batch](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/) or [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/). These two frameworks can automate the downloading/uploading functionality you are after and let you define the file parsing in a well structured manner. If you are after csv or line-by-line parsing it's already done for you and you'll be at the file parsing bit just with a few configuration. Take a look at the [Spring Batch sample examples](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/trunk/spring-batch-samples/) and [Apache Camel examples](http://camel.apache.org/examples.html) as a starting point.

Comment: Yes i need to parse CSV as well, may be excel and xml too.  After reading, processing and uploading, i have to call a web service..... OK i go for the spring-batch.Thanks for your response :)

Comment: Hi Basit, if you are happy with the response you can upvote or even accept.